# Why are Python scripts not found by "which"?

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, command-line

I have a Python script called `aws` that is stored in `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin` on my computer that runs under Mac OSX 10.12.6. The folder is also listed in the `PATH` environment variable so that I can invoke `aws` from the command line. `aws` is found and it works nicely.

What puzzles me is that the `which` command line utility does not see the `aws` script. Example:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
$ which aws
$
```

Why does it find `vim` but does not find `aws`?

Comment: this seems to be a similar issue as to one addressed in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73965/why-which-command-does-not-give-you-the-correct-path).  In short "`which` is an external program, which tries to determine how your shell will resolve a command from the existing $PATH, but it is possible for it to get it wrong."

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did "type aws" and it says "aws is /Users/myself/Library/Python/3.6/bin/aws".

Comment: Try using `type -p`

Comment: This source code may help you to understand why it ignores your aws script: https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/which/which.c

Comment: what does ‘ls -l aws’ show, in that directory?